# Spotipy can't access user's info using SpotifyOAuth (authorization flow error)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, spotipy

I'm trying to do an API using spotify, and spotipy (I use django rest framework for this).

I followed the documentation and when I use

> SpotifyClientCredentials

It works just fine but I can't access user's information (in my exemple I try to get the username). To do this, spotipy tells me to use

> SpotifyOAuth

But then things get worse, I have a "test" endpoint and when I connect my account, postman opens TONS of tabs

> https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=....&response_type=code&redirect_uri=...

Here is my code :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        urn = 'spotify:artist:3jOstUTkEu2JkjvRdBA5Gu'
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=envi.SECRET_ID, client_secret=envi.SECRET_PASS, redirect_uri=envi.SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI))

        artist = sp.artist(urn)
        print(artist)

        user = sp.current_user()
        print(user)
        return JsonResponse(test, safe=False)
```

It's just the code from the documentation, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by stocking the access token in the database and I created another spotipy object with that token (not the best pratice to do, because I've the access token in the database, but it worked).